# Indexing a tensor in the 3rd dimension

Tags: python, indexing, theano, deep-learning

I have a batch of `N` sequences of integers of length `L` which is embedded into a `N*L*d` tensor. This sequence is auto-encoded by my network architecture. So, I have:

```
from theano import tensor as T
X = T.imatrix('X')  # N*L elements in [0,C]
EMB = T.tensor('Embedding')  # N*L*d
...  # some code goes here :-)
PY = T.tensor('PY')  # N*L*C probability of the predicted class in [0,C]
cost = -T.log(PY[X])
```

as far as I could get, the indexing is in the first dimension of the tensor, so I had to use a `theano.scan`. Is there a way to index the tensor directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want a 3 dimensional version of [`theano.tensor.nnet.categorical_crossentropy`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/nnet/nnet.html#tensor.nnet.categorical_crossentropy)?

If so, then I think you could simply flatten the matrix of true class label indexes into a vector and the 3D tensor of predicted class probabilities into a matrix and then use the built in function.

```
cost = T.nnet.categorical_crossentropy(
    Y.reshape((Y.shape[0] * Y.shape[1], X.shape[2])),
    X.flatten())
```

The order of entries in `Y` may need to be adjusted first (e.g. via a `dimshuffle`) to make sure the entries in the matrix and vector being compared correspond to each other.

Here we assume, as the question suggests, that the sequences are not padded -- they are all exactly `L` elements in length. If the sequences are actually padded then you may need to do something much more complicated to avoid computing cost elements inside the padding regions.